# Window 7: Files are marked for add in perforce

Tags: perforce

Accidentally I have selected one folder in perforce and click Add sign. And so many files are showing as “marked for Add” files in Perforce which were auto generated in my local drive and I don't want to add it. How can I reverse that in windows 7? I am using Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2015.1/1233444.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can simply Revert those files, they should not be deleted, but they will be removed from the "Marked for Add" list.  Right-click on a file and Revert it, see what happens - for me, that works.

Comment: @S.Shil - Anytime - Perforce is such a great tool!